# Error:Module 'app': platform 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19' not found

Tags: android-studio, google-glass, google-gdk

at first, I'm using Android studio 3.0.1

When I'm following GDK fast start in "https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start#setting_up_the_development_environment", I had a big prob

> Error:Module 'app': platform 'Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19' not found.

I went around the internet and found the cause, but I could not solve the problem.

I installed the Sdk platform 19 and Glass Development Kit Preview 19 exactly, but I keep getting errors.

According to Android Studio version 3.0.1, I have changed the text in gradle-wrapper.properties as follows:

`distributionUrl = https \: //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip`,

I try to change the build version to the latest version, and it does not work even if I follow the answer to the question in the stack overflow.

I need help.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @user3298823 I'm sorry... didn't work yet ...:(

Comment: It's ok, I ended up getting it working.

Comment: I have respond to same question right now in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943985/google-glass-sdk-gradle-sync-failed-cause-failed-to-find-target-google-inc-g/49191361#49191361